# How to reference to json node / child... how do I access the string value of this?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

Im using youtube api (via flash builder / AS3) and loading video data (title, description, id, etc.) successfully using the following:

```
thistitle = myJSONdata.feed.entry[thiscount].title.$t;
thisdesc = myJSONdata.feed.entry[thiscount].media$group.media$description.$t;
thislink = myJSONdata.feed.entry[thiscount].id.$t;
thisimg = myJSONdata.feed.entry[thiscount].id.$t;
```

but when it comes to loading the thumbnail image which is at:

```
feed
 - entry
   - entry
     - media$group
        -media$thumbnail
          - 0
            -url
```

I've tried virtually everything I can think of and searches yield no results for json speciifically... heres what I tried last:

```
thisimg = myJSONdata.feed.entry[thiscount].media$group.media$thumbnail.Object(0).url;
```

how  do I access this particular element of the json data with actionscript and flash builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thisimg = myJSONdata.feed.entry[thiscount].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;

Comment: awesome - thanks.   will make note for future json / flex / flash adventures!